# Public key authentication and change of password

Tags: authentication, public-key

I have set up public key authentication for my Raspberry server.

If I change the password of the user authenticated by the public key, shall I recreate the public key?

Please advise.
Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Generally, in case that you are using pubkey auth, and Raspberry connected to internet, I would recommend to disable password auth to prevent brootforce of your passwd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Public key authentication is used independently the account password.

Also changing the password protection on the private key (which you can't do as the server admin on the server and needs to be done by the user on the client),  does not change the public key.

A user only needs to upload a new public key when they *replace* their private key.